# Do you unlock Quidditch later in the game?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

I know throughout the game that various students are upset that Quidditch was canceled and not happening this year.

But does Quidditch get reinstated later in the year?

Especially since there is a Quidditch field right next to the school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**.

On the [official Hogwarts Legacy FAQ page](https://www.hogwartslegacy.com/en-us/faq), Warner Bros has confirmed that Quidditch will not be playable in Hogwarts Legacy:

> Quidditch is not playable in Hogwarts Legacy. However, broom flight for traversal and broom race challenges are part of the game. Players can also fly brooms to explore new and familiar locations surrounding Hogwarts Castle.

[image: Q: Is Quidditch playable in Hogwarts Legacy?]

Even though Quidditch isn't available in the game, you are however able to purchase and fly a broom within the game.